# Dojo Build Error - ReferenceError: dojo is not defined

Tags: build, dojo

I'm doing a custom build with dojo 1.6.1.

I get this error: ReferenceError: dojo is not defined.

I reduced the profile to a simple file like this:

```
dependencies ={
    layers:  [
        {
            name: "myRelease.js",
            dependencies: [
        "dijit._Widget",
        "dijit._Templated"          
           ]
       }
    ],
    prefixes: [
    [ "dijit", "../dijit" ]
   ]
};
```

but I still get the same error.

Why is dojo undefined? what am I doing wrong?

THanks

Comment: Are you sure, dojo reference is intact?

Comment: reference where? There's no reference to dojo in the profile, correct? at least I do not see it in any of the examples. The build starts by putting dojo and dijit in the release directory then it says dojo is not defined.

Comment: build output:

E:\SOFTWARE\BGS\BGS\util\buildscripts>java -classpath ../shrinksafe/js.jar;../sh
rinksafe/shrinksafe.jar org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main build.js action=
release profile=bgsrelease3 releaseDir=../../REL1
release:  Using profile: profiles/bgsrelease3.profile.js
release:  Using version number: 0.0.0.dev for the release.
release:  Copying: ../../dojo/../dijit to: ../../REL1/dojo/dijit
release:  Copying: ../../dojo to: ../../REL1/dojo/dojo
release:  Building dojo.js and layer files
js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: ReferenceError: "dojo" is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Add the following script to HTML to add DOJO build support

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

Comment: But isn't this exactly what you want to avoid? You want to have one single JS file containing all the dojo code. That is the sole purpose of doing a build, isn't it?